# What's the name of this plant/weed? See picture below

Tags: identification, weeds

I'm thinking this is a weed. It's growing in one part of my backyard. Its really hard to uproot the plant. The root is thick and even the small plants grow off of the left over root in the ground. If I try to pull it with bare hands, the core of the stem stays only the outer cover with the leaves come off. Its slippery too. Has anyone seen this and know how to get rid of it?

[image]
[image]

EDIT: I live in the pacific northwest near Seattle.

Comment: Where are you located? It makes it easier for people to answer the question with this information. Similarly, you could search for weeds common to your area, or call a local agricultural college or gardening society/nursery and get more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  think its a Dock, maybe Broad leaved Dock (Rumex obtusifolius), pic below

http://thepoisondiaries.tumblr.com/post/65918102719/rumex-obtusifolius-broad-leaved-dock-the

It has a taproot that may go down as far as 150 cm in soils it likes, and is very difficult to dig out because there's usually enough of the tap root left in the ground for it to regrow. Smaller, younger plants should be dug out as soon as they are seen, before the taproot gets too long. Spreads readily by seed, and is a real problem in lawned or grassed areas. As yours isn't in grass, it should be easier to find a herbicide which will kill it because you're not restricted to lawn herbicides. Check in your area what's available. More information in the link below regarding this plant

http://www.plantwise.org/KnowledgeBank/Datasheet.aspx?dsid=48064